# Clarification on the proof of theorem 8 (Set Theory and Metric Spaces - Kaplansky)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are 2 parts (red underline and yellow highlight) in the proof below that I couldn’t follow.

1. Devise **a** one-to-one map of A onto C. Doesn’t the article ‘**a**’ mean ‘**one**’? However, the proof says: take *g* = the identity (for set *D*) AND take *g* = *f* (for unilateral cycles *E*). That means **two** instead of **one** function *g*, doesn’t it?
2. Is it a typo for the highlighted phrase (*C* might adjoin to *A*)? It should be *C* might adjoin to *f*(*A*) instead, shouldn’t it?

Could someone please help clarify? Thank you in advance. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, we are constructing *one* function on $A$, but *separately* on $D$ and (two parts of) $E$.
   Starting from the given example, $f(A)=D\cup\{a_2,a_3,\dots\}\cup\{b_2,b_3,\dots\}\cup \dots$, assume specifically that $C=f(A)\cup\{b_1,c_1\}$.
   Then set $g(x)=x$ if $x\in D$, 
   $g(x)=x$ if $x\in \{b_1,b_2,\dots,\,c_1,c_2,\dots\}$, 
   and $g(x)=f(x)$ otherwise (so that if $x\in \{a_1,a_2,\dots,\,d_1,d_2,\dots,\dots\}$).
2. Yes, it is a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @Berci. If there are TWO functions *g* from *A* to *C*, then the proof failed to prove the point of there exists ONE function mapping between the two sets in question?

Comment: It's just an abuse of notation. First they say $g|_D$ is an arbitrary bijection of $D$, say the identity or $f$, then they don't define $E_1$ only by words: as the elements $x$ of $E$ for which the whole $f$-chain of $x$  (and in particular, its initial element) is contained in $C$, and then $g|_{E_1}$ must be the identity, and on the rest, $E_2:=E\setminus E_1$, they write to define $g|_{E_2}$ as $f|_{E_2}$. It is *one* mapping.

Comment: Thanks, @Berci. This makes it much clearer. One more thing: because *g* |E1 must be the identity, that means it doesn't count as as separate function from *g* |E2 (*f* |E2)? I've just seen your edited answer, it's so much more succinct. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Well. Technically *three* functions are defined here, but note that their domains are disjoint with the union of the whole base set $A$. Since a function is set theoretically just the set of pairs $(x,f(x))$, we can calmly take the union of these 3 functions to get $g$.